# Javascript selection undefined

Tags: javascript

One of my web app using RichTextBox control from .Net 2.0, the purpose of using it to allow user add/edit content on the fly.  This is an old app but it functions as no issue.  But since we update DevExpress 16.1 from 14.5 version,  things went sour, the app stopped working.
All the icons that using javascript stop working.  For example I got undefined value for globalDoc.selection.type

Here is a sample of insert a hyperlink on .cs
//Insert our own custom hyperlink

```
RichTextBoxControl.ToolbarButton tbInsertLink = new 
RichTextBoxControl.ToolbarButton("InsertLink", true);
tbInsertLink.Title = "Insert web address or email link";
tbInsertLink.ClientOnClickFunction = "CustomHyperlink";
RTB_editor.CreateToolbarButton(tbInsertLink);
layoutStr.Append(tbInsertLink.Name);
```

And below are function on .aspx page.  The error starts are globalDoc.selection.type

```
function CustomHyperlink(editor, htmlmode) {
  if (!htmlmode) {
    editor.focus();
    ShowCustomLinkDialog(editor);
  } else {
    alert("To use the toolbar, change the HTML view setting");
  }
}

function ShowCustomLinkDialog(editor) {
  var globalDoc = editor.document;
  var rngLink;
  var elmLink;

  if ("Control" == globalDoc.selection.type) {
    RTB_rngMaster = globalDoc.selection.createRange();
    if (1 == RTB_rngMaster.length) {
      RTB_rngMaster = RTB_getTextRange(RTB_rngMaster(0));
      RTB_rngMaster.select();
    }
  }
  if (
    "Text" == globalDoc.selection.type ||
    "None" == globalDoc.selection.type
  ) {
    RTB_rngMaster = globalDoc.selection.createRange();
    //URL is always selected by default
    document.all("radioURL").checked = true;
    elmLink = RTB_findParentTag("A", RTB_rngMaster);
    if (null != elmLink) {
      rngLink = RTB_getTextRange(elmLink);
      if (rngLink.compareEndPoints("StartToStart", RTB_rngMaster) < 0) {
        RTB_rngMaster.setEndPoint("StartToStart", rngLink);
      }
      if (rngLink.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", RTB_rngMaster) > 0) {
        RTB_rngMaster.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", rngLink);
      }
      RTB_rngMaster.select();
      if ("" != elmLink.href) {
        //see what type of link this is
        var _linkTxt = elmLink.href;
        var _index = _linkTxt.indexOf("mailto:");
        if (_index == 0) {
          //strip out the mailto from showing
          _linkTxt = _linkTxt.substr(7);
          document.all("radioEmail").checked = true;
        }
        document.getElementById("Custom_txtUrl").value = _linkTxt;
      } else {
        // no href
        document.getElementById("Custom_txtUrl").value = "";
      }
    } else {
      //New Selection
      document.getElementById("Custom_txtUrl").value = "";
    }
    RTB_showDialog(editor, CustomLinkDialog, CustomLinkDialogCallback);
    document.all("Custom_txtUrl").focus();
  }
}
```

Although on this web page I didn’t use any control any of DevExpress control, but the project as a whole has reference in DevExpress assemblies and use for different applications.

I am not sure why D.E. causes issue to RichTextBox control javascript.  Please help!

Thanks

JC

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/type `document.getSelection()` is missing in your code

Comment: @romuleald here is what I tried to add to ShowCustomLinkDialog function after var elmLink.
var selection;
selection = editor.document.getSelection();  At the debug, I tried selectcion.type, it returns undefined.

Comment: Here are what editor.document.getSelection() returns from debug immediate window:
{...}
    [Methods]: {...}
    anchorNode: {...}
    anchorOffset: 0
    focusNode: {...}
    focusOffset: 0
    isCollapsed: true
    rangeCount: 1